# Detect if program should log to systemd journal or stdout

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am updating a suite of programs for RHEL7, some [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), some [java](/questions/tagged/java). If they're started as systemd services I would like them to write to the systemd journal. If they're run directly at the terminal, say for testing, I want them to write to stdout instead. How can I do this most elegantly?

I want to take advantage of the journal's advanced features -- logging severity, file name, line number, thread name, etc. -- so simply writing to stdout doesn't suffice.

The searching I've done yielded advice to check the process's parent PID, or check its cgroup. Is there a better way? Those seem like kludgy solutions. Ideally there'd be a function I could call, or an environment variable to check.

Additional info:

- For the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) programs I plan to call [sd_journal_print(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_print.html).
- For the [java](/questions/tagged/java) programs I plan to use SLF4J + Logback + [logback-journal](https://github.com/gnieh/logback-journal).

(My fallback plan is to use a command-line switch, but it'd sure be nice to autodetect.)

Comment: How about `isatty(3)` to see if a terminal is attached? (though I'd probably go with a `-d` debug flag, as something has to manually signal that, so less surprises if a terminal is somehow detected when it shouldn't)

Comment: @thrig Using `isatty` wouldn't do distinguish between execution by systemd and execution where the output is going to a file (if someone runs `johnsprogram >johnsprogram.log` then logging on stdout is clearly desired).

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In systemd version 231 the `JOURNAL_STREAM` environment variable was introduced for this very purpose.  Your program checks its value, compares its value against the device and i-node number of its standard error, and changes its behaviour accordingly.

When *not* connected to the journal, you could (of course) always employ something like JSON written (as a single line per object) to standard error, to have structured log records there too.  RFC 5424 also has (more limited) structured data options.

Answer (score 4):

`systemd` already handles this case elegantly for you, as documented in [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).

Log to STDOUT. When run via systemd, systemd will default to redirecting STDOUT to the journal.

Another option is `journal+console` if you always want to log to both.

Logging to STDOUT is also a best practice in the [12 Factor App design](https://12factor.net/logs).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to take advantage of the journal's advanced features -- logging severity, file name, line number, thread name, etc.